# [ariac/gear] Could not load controller 'ariac/arm'

Tags: ros, gazebo7

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'd normally open an issue against osrf/gear; but there doesn't seem to be an issues tab on the Bitbucket repository.

I'm having some issues launching the GEAR examples.  Namely, when I do `roslaunch osrf_gear sample.launch`, gazebo opens with the simulation but the arm seems to appear on the ground and only moves very slowly.

[image: Arm on the ground]

I also get these error messages when launching:

`[ERROR] [1472745023.718771045, 0.001000000]: Could not load controller 'ariac/arm' because controller type 'effort_controllers/JointTrajectoryController' does not exist.`

`[ERROR] [1472745023.718824000, 0.001000000]: Use 'rosservice call controller_manager/list_controller_types' to get the available types`

`Error when loading ariac/arm`

`[ERROR] [1472745023.728961885, 0.009000000]: Could not start controller with name ariac/arm because no controller with this name exists`

I thought it may be as simple as me missing `effort_controllers` but I seem to have them installed already.  It seems as if the controller plugin is not existent?

For reference, I wrote this script to do my environment setup so this is what I am using: https://github.com/cwru-robotics/cwru_scripts/blob/master/ariac/ariac.sh

Thanks in advance for any help anyone may be able to give.

-Luc

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242921/%5Bariac/gear%5D-could-not-load-controller-%27ariac/arm%27/) by [luc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18958/luc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 350 on 2016-09-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [luc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18958/luc/) on 2016-09-01**:
Also - the support forum for GEAR seems to be only available to OSRF employees: https://groups.google.com/a/osrfoundation.org/d/forum/ariac-support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out I didn't have `ros-indigo-joint-trajectory-controller` installed.  Oopz.

Do a `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-joint-trajectory-controller` and have a nice day.

---

Originally posted by [luc](https://answers.ros.org/users/18958/luc/) with karma: 350 on 2016-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1